# Why won't pydeck display any coordinates?

Tags: python, json, scatter-plot, pydeck

I have a large JSON with the data for dozens of locations, which I am trying to plot on a map using pydeck. The output map doesn't display any points in the area, and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code:

```
import pydeck as pdk

data = insert local json here

layer = pdk.Layer(
    "ScatterplotLayer",
    data,
    pickable=True,
    opacity=0.8,
    stroked=True,
    filled=True,
    radius_scale=6,
    radius_min_pixels=1,
    radius_max_pixels=100,
    line_width_min_pixels=1,
    get_position=['lon', 'lat'],
    get_fill_color=[255, 140, 0],
    get_line_color=[0, 0, 0],
)


# Set the viewport location
view_state = pdk.ViewState(latitude=59.10816422596582, longitude=18.384297022641775, zoom=9, bearing=0, pitch=0)

# Render
r = pdk.Deck(layers=[layer], initial_view_state=view_state, tooltip={"text": "{name}"})
r.to_html("scatterplot_layer.html")
```

The JSON is huge so here is a sample of it:

```
{'elements': [{'id': 358356239,
   'lat': 59.3207673,
   'lon': 18.1549076,
   'tags': {'man_made': 'lighthouse',
    'name': 'Blockhusudden',
    'seamark:light:1:character': 'Fl',
    'seamark:light:1:colour': 'red',
    'seamark:light:1:group': '2',
    'seamark:light:1:height': '6',
    'seamark:light:1:period': '6',
    'seamark:light:1:range': '4',
    'seamark:light:1:sector_end': '222',
    'seamark:light:2:character': 'Fl',
    'seamark:light:2:colour': 'green',
    'seamark:light:2:group': '2',
    'seamark:light:2:height': '6',
    'seamark:light:2:period': '6',
    'seamark:light:2:range': '3',
    'seamark:light:2:sector_end': '244',
    'seamark:light:2:sector_start': '222',
    'seamark:light:3:character': 'Fl',
    'seamark:light:3:colour': 'white',
    'seamark:light:3:group': '2',
    'seamark:light:3:height': '6',
    'seamark:light:3:period': '6',
    'seamark:light:3:range': '6',
    'seamark:light:3:sector_end': '86.5',
    'seamark:light:3:sector_start': '244',
    'seamark:light:reference': 'C 6558',
    'seamark:name': 'Blockhusudden',
    'seamark:type': 'light_minor',
    'wikidata': 'Q10431416'},
   'type': 'node'}]
}
```

I am aware that my JSON has single quotes instead of double quotes, but this is the data I need to work with. The issue persists even if the single quotes are replaced with double quotes.

Comment: have you tried with `radius_min_pixels=50` ?